# Can i create two tables at single time while installation of custom plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Hi i want to know can i create two `tables` while installing my custom plugin. This is the way i am creating the `tables` in database

```
   function wnm_install(){
global $wpdb;
global $wnm_db_version;

$sms_table = $wpdb->prefix . "smsfactory";
if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '". $sms_table . "'") != $sms_table){ 
$sql_sms_table = "CREATE TABLE ". $sms_table . "     (
SfID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
sf_name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
start_duration date NOT NULL,
end_duration date NOT NULL,
activity varchar(500) NOT NULL,
survey_settings varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`limit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
goal varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (SfID)
) ";
}


$sms_message_table = $wpdb->prefix . "smsfactorymessagetemplate";
if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '". $sms_message_table . "'") != $sms_message_table){ 
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ". $sms_message_table . "   (
sfID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
sftemplate_name varchar(256) NOT NULL,
sftemplate_type varchar(128) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (sfID)
) ";
}
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
dbDelta($sql);
add_option("wnm_db_version", $wnm_db_version);
}
```

Now problem with this code is it creates the second table and skip the first one so please tell me any solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me you are just executing one query: `dbDelta($sql);`.

Have you tried adding `dbDelta($sql_sms_table);`?

Answer (score 6):

In your original code, you were only calling `dbDelta($sql)` and not `dbDelta($sql_sms_table)` also.

#### A better way...

`dbDelta()` can take an array of queries, so we need to set an empty array on the `$sql` variable to store the queries if their conditions evaluate `true`.

```
function wnm_install() {

    global $wpdb, $wnm_db_version;

    $sql = array();

    //sms table
    $sms_table = $wpdb->prefix . "smsfactory";

    if( $wpdb->get_var("show tables like '". $sms_table . "'") !== $sms_table ) { 

        $sql[] = "CREATE TABLE ". $sms_table . "     (
        SfID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        sf_name varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        start_duration date NOT NULL,
        end_duration date NOT NULL,
        activity varchar(500) NOT NULL,
        survey_settings varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        `limit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        goal varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (SfID)
        ) ";

    }

    //sms messages table
    $sms_message_table = $wpdb->prefix . "smsfactorymessagetemplate";
    
    if( $wpdb->get_var("show tables like '". $sms_message_table . "'") !== $sms_message_table ) { 

        $sql[] = "CREATE TABLE ". $sms_message_table . "   (
        sfID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        sftemplate_name varchar(256) NOT NULL,
        sftemplate_type varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (sfID)
        ) ";

    }


    if ( !empty($sql) ) {

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

        dbDelta($sql);
        add_option("wnm_db_version", $wnm_db_version);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: So i can same `$sql` variable to create multiple table at single time ?

Comment: Yes only if it is an array of queries. `$sql[] = 'query1'` ... `$sql[] = 'query2'` ...if you are only passing one query then you can just pass a string not an array, e.g. `$sql = 'query'`. Otherwise you have to call `dbDelta($somevariable)` multiple times.

Comment: Yes works for me but when i did paste your code it doesn't create the table i just put the `dbDelta($sql_sms_table);` under the first table i am creating now it is working fine creating the table.

Comment: Didn't know about putting multiple queries in array. Nice to know - will test it :)

Comment: @Steven Pretty handy... intertnally `dbDelta()` converts single string based queries into an array anyway.

Comment: Well i am taking my words back it is working properly but i am getting `The plugin generated 4 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.` after installing plugin

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed!